# Matrix of transformation

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

I have just finished understanding the topic of matrix of the transformation, and we just started T-invariant subspaces.

Can anyone please help me with these questions, because I don't know how to approach them. This is not homework by the way, it is just for my understanding.

1) Suppose $B=(w_1, w_2, \dots, w_k, v_1, \dots, v_{n-k})$ is a basis for $V$ and $W$ = Span$(w_1, \ldots, w_k)$ is T-invariant. What does the matrix of $T$ with respect to $B$ look like?

2) Suppose $V$ is the direct sum of $W_1$ and $W_2$, with $W_1,W_2$ both T-invariant. If $B=(u_1,u_2, \ldots, u_n, z_1,z_2, \dots, z_n)$ is a basis for V with the $u$'s being a basis for $W_1$ and the $z$'s being a basis for $W_2$, what does the matrix of T with respect to $B$ look like?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The columns of your matrix tell you what vectors your basis get sent to under $T$.  So, in your first problem, if $W$ is $T$ invariant, then for each $1\leq i\leq k$
$$
T(w_i)=a_1w_1+\cdots +a_kw_k+0v_1+0v_2+\cdots +0v_{n-k}.
$$
Thus the $i$th column of your matrix will be
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 \\ a_2 \\ \vdots \\ a_k \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
for $1\leq i\leq k$.  The columns corresponding to the $v_i$ have no restrictions.

For your second question the columns for the $u_i$ will have this form.  The columns for the $z_i$ will have $0$'s on top.